# What happens if event loop is already filled and I raise some event (such as button click)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom-events

Let's say my event loop is already having tasks in queue and now I click on some button, what will happen now? i.e. whether the click event will get passed to `Event_Queue` and queued up and will occur after the previous task gets executed?

Comment: Hard to tell for sure, there are several task queues all with different priorities, there is even [a proposal to add a TaskController](https://github.com/WICG/main-thread-scheduling/) that could allow authors to control how tasks are prioritized.